# Android PhoneGap App not working properly after eclipse export

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, export, keystore

My Application, which is uploading some pictures via https on a server, works fine if I run it via eclipse or install the generated .apk from the sd-card.
But if I export the project to add a keystore and install the apk from the sd-card it's not working properly.
It seems that the applications can't get a connection to the server at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been solved!

Ive been using https to connect to the server, after changing it to http everything works fine!